# error en claves foraneas

Tags: mysql

este el codigo solo para crear tres tablas y relacionarlas, me gustaria saber por que me da el error que mensiono en la parte de abajo.

```
CREATE TABLE productos (
    id_producto INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id_producto ),
    nombre VarChar(150),
    precio int 
);
CREATE TABLE clientes (id_cliente int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                       PRIMARY KEY (id_cliente),
                       nombre VarChar(100),
                       apellido VarChar(100),
                      edad int,
                       telefono int 

);
CREATE TABLE pedidos (id_pedido int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                      PRIMARY KEY (id_pedido),
                      FECHA DATE,
                      cantidad INT,
                      id_cliente INT,
                      id_producto INT,
                      FOREIGN KEY (id_cliente) REFERENCES id_clientes(id_cliente),
                       FOREIGN KEY (id_producto) REFERENCES id_productos(id_producto)
)
consulta SQL:


CREATE TABLE pedidos (id_pedido int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                      PRIMARY KEY (id_pedido),
                      FECHA DATE,
                      cantidad INT,
                      id_cliente INT,
                      id_producto INT,
                      FOREIGN KEY (id_cliente) REFERENCES id_clientes(id_cliente),
                       FOREIGN KEY (id_producto) REFERENCES id_productos(id_producto)
)
```

MySQL ha dicho: Documentación

> ## 1005 - No puedo crear tabla `proyecto`.`pedidos` (Error: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! donde esta el create de la tabla proyecto?

Answer (score 0):

segun veo estas creando la tabla pedidos 2 veces, creo que ese es el error

```
CREATE TABLE pedidos (id_pedido int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                      PRIMARY KEY (id_pedido),
                      FECHA DATE,
                      cantidad INT,
                      id_cliente INT,
                      id_producto INT,
                      FOREIGN KEY (id_cliente) REFERENCES id_clientes(id_cliente),
                       FOREIGN KEY (id_producto) REFERENCES id_productos(id_producto)
)
consulta SQL:

CREATE TABLE pedidos (id_pedido int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                      PRIMARY KEY (id_pedido),
                      FECHA DATE,
                      cantidad INT,
                      id_cliente INT,
                      id_producto INT,
                      FOREIGN KEY (id_cliente) REFERENCES id_clientes(id_cliente),
                       FOREIGN KEY (id_producto) REFERENCES id_productos(id_producto)
)
```